# synch, restore, backup

Tags: backup

I'm afraid I messed up my Iphone.  I plugged it into my computer for the first time ever.  It prompted me to backup so I did (silly me).  At the end of the back up it prompted me to log in with my son's account instead of mine.  Now my phone info is gone and my son's phone from 2011 is on my phone and my phone is gone!  Help

Answer (score 1):

If you backed up your phone to the computer then you should be able to restore that backup to your iphone using itunes. If not hopefully you set icloud as your backup. You can restore your phone from icloud using these directions: http://support.apple.com/kb/ph12521. Hope it helps.